# Counting total posts by a user in the blade view

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-blade

I have sent a collection of all posts in my blog to my index view and then used the following code to count the total posts made by each user.

```
<p class="joined-text">Posts: {{count(App\Posts::where('user_id', $post->user->id)->get())}}</p>
```

Is this bad practice to do this from within the blade view?  If it is how would I achieve this?

Models

```
class Posts extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comments::class, 'post_id');
    }
}





class User extends Authenticatable
{

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('\App\Posts::class');
    }

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comments::class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple solution:

```
<p class="joined-text">Posts: {{ App\Posts::where('user_id', $post->user_id)->count() }}</p>
```

**Updated**

Complete and better solution:

`Post.php`:

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(App\User::class);
}
```

`User.php`:

```
public function posts(){
    return $this->hasMany(App\Post::class);
}
public function getPostsCountAttribute(){
    return $this->posts()->count();
}
```

blade:

```
<p class="joined-text">Posts: {{ $post->user->posts_count }}</p>
```

Comment: It's bad because you query in view!

Comment: @MahdiYounesi Ok. You are right! That was a simple solution only.

Comment: Thank you .  That's what I wanted.  I tried to incorporate it into the model as a method but I was struggling.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is bad.

You could use [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) if have the `user_id` field in `posts` table

```
class User extends Model
{
  public function posts()
  {
     return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
  }
}
```

In controller

```
return view('sth')->with(['posts'=>$user->posts]);
```

Then in view

```
$posts->count();
```

Or just getting counts if you don't need posts

```
$postCount = $user->posts()->count();
```

Comment: I have user_id in my post table.  Where do I use $user->posts();