# Show number of reservations user have made in admin's user list page

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-datatables

I want to count the number of reservation users made in admin panel using [Laravel Datatables](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables).

**Reservation model**

```
public function customer()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'customer_id');
  }
```

**User model**

```
public function reservations()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(Reservation::class);
  }

  public function getUsersCountAttribute()
  {
    return $this->reservations()->count();
  }
```

**Userdatatable**

```
->editColumn('user_reservation', function(Reservation $reservation){
     return $reservation->customer->users_count;
  });
```

... However, - it throws an error saying:

> Argument 1 passed to App\DataTables\Admin\UserDataTable::App\DataTables\Admin\{closure}() must be an instance of App\Models\Reservation, instance of App\Models\User given,

I tried following the steps mentioned in
[Counting total posts by a user in the blade view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48721466/counting-total-posts-by-a-user-in-the-blade-view)
... but it didn't help..

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a table of users? So, I supose your callback function expects to be given a `User` model. And the `User` model has a `users_count` attribute that contains the number of reservations.

```
->editColumn('user_reservation', function(User $user) {
    return $user->users_count;
});
```

Comment: I did as you mentioned..but throws error 

**Exception Message:\n\nSQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'reservations.user_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `reservations` where `reservations`.`user_id` = 54 and `reservations`.`user_id` is not null)"}**

Comment: I just solved it..In **User** model, I just add the foreign key `customer_id` i.e

public function reservations()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Reservation::class, 'customer_id');
    }
as my foreign id is not user_id...thank u @Jerodev for your time -:)