# Laravel WithCount using where

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

i have 3  tables :

1. Table 1 
   `courses` :

   - id_cours
   - field_cours
2. Table 2 
   `Question` :

   - id_quest
   - field_quest
   - id_cours
   - id_user
3. Table 3 
   `Users` :
   -id
   -nom

The question is i want to Count all question just added by the user logged .

i try with this one in the Model Courses  :
but i want to add where id_user = id

```
 public function answers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\QuestionUsers','idcours', 'id_cours');

    }
```

but this returns count of all question added by all users . Please need Help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Counting total posts by a user in the blade view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48721466/counting-total-posts-by-a-user-in-the-blade-view)

Answer (score 0):

i found solution just i call the Auth and add where

```
 public function answers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\QuestionUsers','idcours', 'id_cours')->where('idusers',Auth::id());

    }
```

Comment: where you use WithCount??